# Two identical String will not equal to true

Tags: android, string, kotlin, equals

I want to compare two String objects coming out of two different lists and no matter if i use
`equals()`, `contentEquals()` or `==`, it is always false.

Has it something to do with how the strings of the first list are put into it?

edit: it's getting weirder look at the log outcome in this picture:

[image]

```
                        DictWord.dictWords.forEach {
                            Log.i("testen", "it is: $it and equals 'black'? - ${it.equals("black")}")
                            Log.i("testen", "it is: $it and equals $newWord - ${it.equals(newWord)}")
                            Log.i("testen", "it is: $it and equals $newWord - ${it.contentEquals("black")}")
                            Log.i("testen", "it is: $it and == $newWord - ${it == newWord}")
                            Log.i("black", "it is: 'black' and equals $newWord - ${"black" == newWord}")


...    subStrainsAdapter.addHeaderAndSubmitList(null)
            var textList = mutableListOf<String>()
            var movingText = ""
            thoughtContent.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
                override fun beforeTextChanged(
                    s: CharSequence,
                    start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
                override fun onTextChanged(
                    s: CharSequence,
                    start: Int, before: Int, count: Int)
                {movingText += s.last()}
            })

            //SUBSTRAIN INPUT - goes to onSubStrainEditEnd above when ENTER hit
            thoughtContent.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener {
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                override fun onKey(v: View?, key: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
                    return if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
                        textList.add(movingText)
                        movingText = ""
                        false } else false
                }})
```

Output log for the above code:
[image: Outcome of the logging]

edit

```
 if(b == false) {
                    thoughtsViewModel.editThought(thoughtContent.text.toString(), thoughtItem.id)
                    val testList = thoughtContent.text.toString().split(" ")
                    textList.forEach {
                        (Log.i("testen", "it is $it"))
                        if(DictWord.dictWords.keys.contains(it)) {Log.i("testen", "TRIGGGEERRRED and its $it")}
                    }
                    testList.forEach {
                        (Log.i("testen", "it is $it"))
                        if(DictWord.dictWords.keys.contains(it)) {Log.i("testen", "test list TRIGGGEERRRED and its $it")}
                    }
```

Comment: proper check for content equality for `String` is `equals` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newWord` is not trimmed it seems. From your log, it has an extra space before it.

[image]

These two lines in the log correspond to this code respectively:

```
Log.i("testen", "it is: $it and equals 'black'? - ${it.equals("black")}")
Log.i("testen", "it is: $it and equals $newWord - ${it.equals(newWord)}")
```

You can see that you didn't add two spaces in the second line but still your black has an extra space before

---

You should either correct your list or do `newWord.trim()` which will remove all leading and trailing whitespaces

Otherwise you should always use `String.equals(otherString: String)` or `s1 == s2` (they are the same in kotlin)

Comment: yes that was it thanks!
how do i mark this as the answer? im new

Answer (score 0):

Your example is badly formatted and I believe missing some code, but as @snachmsm pointed out, `contentEquals` is a method on arrays in Kotlin. You should use `equals()` for Strings instead (though `==` is the preferred way in Kotlin)